How to add missing months to a dataframe and chronologically order the months?
I am working with the supplementary homicide reports of the FBI containing information on homicide incidents. I want to make a dataframe containing the amount of observations per month per state. The problem is, however, that for each state some months are missing and the months are not in chronological order. I just can't fix those two problems. Here is simple representation of how my data looks only taking 1 state into account:
df <- data.frame(
state = rep("California", 11),
month_of_offense = c("July", "April", "September", "June", "October", "May", "June", "June", "April", "July", "December"))

df <- df %>%
group_by(state, month_of_offense) %>%
summarise(observations = n())


state month_of_offense observations

California  April       2       
California  December    1       
California  July        2       
California  June        3       
California  May         1       
California  October     1       
California  September   1

I tried to use the pad() function from the package Padr, but I could not manage to turn 'month_of_offense', which is a variable of the character type, into a data variable.

Welcome to SO.  Since you haven't told us what values in your month_of_offense looks like, we can't offer concrete advice.  But the lubridate package will definitely be of help.  Once you've converted your dates, tidyr's expand will complete the grid of states and months for you.  This post will help you construct a minimal reproducible example. By providing one, you help yourself by helping others to help you.

I am sorry for the confusion. The 'month_of_offense' variable contains monthly values like 'April', 'May', 'June' and so on. Furthermore, I filtered the data such that I have isolated specific cases of homicide and aggregated the homicide counts per month per state. The problem is, however, that for several  states months are missing. Whats more, the months available are not chronologically ordered.

It would be more helpful if I had your data to play with, but here is something to get going on:
You want to create a "template" dataframe with all possible variables and then merge or join your own data to that template so that you have your zero reporting in appropriate cells.
More specifically you want to left join your known data to your template.
Heres an example with years months and provinces in South Africa:
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)



# Create a template of months from m data x to y for 9 provinces from South Africa
months <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
provinces<- c("Eastern Cape", "Free State", "Gauteng", "KwaZulu-Natal", "Limpopo", "Mpumalanga", "Northern Cape", "North West", "Western Cape")
years <- c(2010:2020)

# we will use the expand.grid function to create all the combinations

df <- expand.grid(months, provinces, years)

# create data with some missing variables for each year, month, and province

df$cases <- rpois(nrow(df), 10)

# make some cases missing at random
df$cases[sample(1:nrow(df), 100)] <- NA

#check missingness
tabyl(is.na(df$cases))

#make your "original" data with missing cases
df_missing<- df %>%na.omit()

#recreate your template
df_template <- expand.grid(months, provinces, years)

# you can have a look at number of rows to check they are different
list( nrow(df_missing), nrow(df_template))

# now do the left_join 

df_complete_with_cases <- left_join(df_template, df_missing)

df_complete_with_cases

You should end up with a dataset that has joined your "orinical dataset, to your missing one and have NA values for the missing variables. You could replace these to zero depending on the next step of your analysis.
Update
You poor first post has been disabled.
try this:
Make a complete df.
template<- expand.grid(state = unique(df$state), month_of_offense = month.name)

You could in theory include all unique(df$var) from your own dataset.
Left join your data to the template. This "inserts" your data onto the template.
zero_reporting_df<- left_join(template, df, by = c("state", "month_of_offense"))%>%
  mutate(observations = ifelse(is.na(observations), 0, observations))

you should get the resulting df:
print(zero_reporting_df)

           state month_of_offense observations
1  California          January            0
2  California         February            0
3  California            March            0
4  California            April            1
5  California              May            1
6  California             June            1
7  California             July            1
8  California           August            0
9  California        September            1
10 California          October            1
11 California         November            0
12 California         December            1


I apologize for the lack of explanation. My dataset contain variables like:  state <- c("arkansas", "arizona", "california", "colorado")  month_of_offense <- c("April", "May", "June")  victim_1_sex <- c("male", "female")  victim_1_relation_to_offender_1 <- c("husband", "wife","girlfriend", "boyfriend")  I added the observations per month per state, however, some months are missing in each state. Furthermore, the month are not in a chronological order. I hope this clarifies a bit.

If you cannot model a solution off my answer then it may be best to look at a good way to post a minimum reproducible example (MRE) for further help.

I added a MRE in my question, hope it clarifies

@WillemVeldhoen see the update to my answer. Your post hasn't been reopened.
